# i get an "Permission denied" error in mingw

Tags: c++, mingw

i am just started learning c++ and im keep getting an error for this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int nFirstNumber;
    int nSeconedNumber;

    cin >> nFirstNumber;
    cin >> nSeconedNumber;

    cout << "result is: " << nSeconedNumber * nFirstNumber;

    system("pause");

    return 0; 
}
```

this is the error:

Permission denied

please help me

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your environment - compiler cannot access the input files or cannot create the executable in the given directory. How do you build your code?

Comment: with ctrl b insublime text. the defult c++ single file run